# Java server for mobile application

Tags: java, mobile, web-applications, java-server

I want to build mobile app. This app will connect to server, upload some data and files, server will perform some manipulation with data and files, and will send results back to app or to email. All server logic writen on java, there are several jars. So I need server. desirable flexible because i don't sure about possible popularity of app. So maybe cloud will be good solution. And i need suggestion, because i can't understand what i need, for example i looked on google side, but there are google app engine and google cloud what i need to choose? Or maybe select something other Amazon and etc.

Thanks

Comment: What more suitable for my purpose?

Comment: What are your requirements and budget? This does not appear to be a programming question...

Comment: I don't understand the question. It looks like you probably want server application with web interface, but you are talking about mobile app. If you really just want some page with the function you mentioned and you want to go with Java, it can be done with tomcat and JSP.

Comment: Yes, i know, that this is not a programming question, sorry. Budget don't know, maybe on first stage i ready pay until 200$/month. About cpu/memory, cpu at least 1,5 memory 200Mb per user on 2-3 seconds. Numbers of user i don't know, therefore i think on cloud....

Comment: I want create mobile app - ios, android, windows. This application will conect to some java server, because i have all code on server side on java. My app will connect to server. I want to know how to select suitable server, on which platform

Comment: 200Mb per user on 2-3 seconds. This means a Transfer - rate (upload) of 100M / s ? Even for download, what bandwidth would you calculate for your server with say 5 clients connected simultaniously? Besides: For 200$/month you could easily rent both a virtual or a root server which would give you most fexibility and control over what to do with it and future expansions.

Comment: No, transfer per user 5-10 Mb, 200Mb i mean RAM.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose an IaaS (as Amazon EC2 instances or Digital Ocean), where you can rent an infrastructure taking care off all the configuration/installation process.  "Old school", as you have to setup everything and take care of software, security, backup or updates.

You can also try a PaaS out where you just need to deploy and then pay as you use. You can easily scale up the memory ram your app needs, or the number of instances you would like to have.

There are several PaaS that you can look at. If you would like to have an overview about how it works on a specific one, you can take a look at [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKGXff0jjWw).